# Not able to open excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, extension

My excel file(shortcut) is saved with file extension .lnk and I m not able to open it so I want to know how to open it or how to remove .lnk extension.

Comment: Is what's saved as a shortcut the Excel application or a workbook?

Comment: It is saved as excel workbook

Answer (score 2):

A `.lnk` file is [a shortcut file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_shortcut#Microsoft_Windows). It's just a shortcut to the Excel file, not the actual Excel file.

If you don't have the Excel file the shortcut points to, then ask whomever sent you the LNK to send you the actual Excel file instead.

Comment: The excel file (shortcut) is created by me only and it use to open earlier but from the past two days its extension has changed to .lnk and its not opening 
how should I make the file compatiable to excel again

Comment: the file will never be compatible with Excel - it's merely a shortcut to the original file… which it can no longer find. See if the original file is where it should be & make a new shortcut

Answer (score 0):

It's link extension - shortcut file. It's a pointer to an .exe file in your system. You can right click on icon after that go to properties and look a path of .exe file.